# linq to entities simple query gives "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

Using sql server 2012 and visual studio 2012 c# .net 4.0

I have a working system, that runs a daily reporting emails, today there was an error, and when i debug it i found out something odd.

i have this simple query ;

```
var rslt = (from p in db.someTable
            where (p.STATS_DATE != null && p.SOME_COL!= null && 
                   p.SOME_COL < enddate && p.SOME_COL> startdate && 
                   this.SOME_LIST.Contains(p.SOME_COL))
            select p);
```

It throws an `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`,

I tried simplifying the query to :

```
var d = (from p in db.someTable where (p.SOME_COL== 3) select p).ToList();
```

got the same error...
i haven't changed anything in the table's structure

i can query the table from sql server management studio and it works,

btw - its a big table

Comment: Are you sure `db` is not null?

Comment: What does the stack trace look like?

Answer (score 1):

OK so i found the problem and here is what it is, if someone else encounters it :

This table did not contained a pk column, so i manually defined some columns on the entity mapping as keys (logically this is good since they really were acting as keys), the problem was that one of these columns were added to the table as null value, and a key cannot be null so it caused a null reference exception.

i tried to set "allow nulls" to true on the entity mapping yet than i was prompt that a key cannot be nullable, so i had to change the table logic itself in the database so it would use a pk (the table is constantly rebuilding itself therefore it was a bit difficult...).

anyway after adding a pk to the table and remapping it to the entity model, the problem was solved.

hope it would help anyone.